# HTTPWatch IE Automation via Ruby out of memory error

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, httpwatch

I am using the HTTPWatch Ruby script to automate Internet Explorer and crawl a website looking for broken links.  See [here](http://www.httpwatch.com/rubywatir/) for information on the ruby site spider script.  After a while the HTTPWatch plugin fails with the following error:

Get Cache Object failed # 1. len = 2048 url = http://domainname/dckh1h0mntja0m8xa1qugzm3n_59c9/dbs.gif?&dcsdat=1284571577008&dcssip=domainname&dcsuri=/closet_detail.aspx&dcsqry=%3Fid=34200&WT.co_f=10.10.30.9-90436560.30102765&WT.vt_sid=10.10.30.9-90436560.30102765.1284565529237&WT.tz=-4&WT.bh=13&WT.ul=en-us&WT.cd=16&WT.sr=1680x1050&WT.jo=Yes&WT.ti=Generics%2520%2526%2520Super%2520Man%2520Center%25E2%2580%2594Testing...&WT.vt_f_tlh=1284571573
Error = 8 : Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Line 858 source.cpp
hr = 0x80070008

(A MiniDump has already been written by this process to )

SafeTerminate
Version: 7.0.26

When I look in task manager IExplorer.exe is taking up like 1.5 Gigs of memory.  I'm wondering if this is a problem of the cache filling up?  Or is this a problem with the URL being too long?  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How is this related to watir?

Comment: The web spider is implemented by creating an instance of the WATIR::IE class and using its goto() method to visit each URL. The WATIR::IE class maintains a copy of Internet Explorer and issues commands to it as required.  Since I don't know where the problem could be, I just threw the tag in there.

Comment: I took a look at their site but could not find that they use Watir. Could you please post a link to the page that has that information?

Comment: is the page too large for IE, perhaps?

Comment: http://www.httpwatch.com/rubywatir/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I was able to answer my own question.  Since HTTPWatch is a IE plug-in that's why it looked like Internet Explorer was running out of memory.  In fact, it is the HTTPWatch log file that is getting so large.  The work-around is to dump the HttpWatch log at an interval using Save() and then Clear().